# One IBAction for multiple NSTimers

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, ibaction

I'm making a simple game in Xcode, where I use NSTimers for different purposes, such as a score timer, a countdown timer, and to move my objects. All of these timers are called when a button is pushed. But the problem is that the score timer makes all the other timers restart, it can be after a second, half a second, it depends on the score timers time interval. I know this, since I've removed the score timer, and then everything works fine.

And also, I'm using an NSInteger to store the score as high score.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

My code:

```
- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {

FuelMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(FuelMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

FuelMovement2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(Fuel2Moving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

RoyMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0035 target:self selector:@selector(RoyMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

ObstacleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0055 target:self selector:@selector(ObstaclesMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

CountDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(TimerCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Scorer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(Scoring) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)Scoring {

ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];

if (ScoreNumber == 500) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:40]];

    [Pling play];

    [ObstacleTimer invalidate];

    ObstacleTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0045 target:self selector:@selector(ObstaclesMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [RoyMovement invalidate];

    RoyMovement2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0025 target:self selector:@selector(RoyMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

if (ScoreNumber == 502) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:35]];

}

if (ScoreNumber == 1000) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:40]];

    [Pling play];

    [ObstacleTimer2 invalidate];

    ObstacleTimer3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0040 target:self selector:@selector(ObstaclesMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [RoyMovement2 invalidate];

    RoyMovement3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0020 target:self selector:@selector(RoyMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

if (ScoreNumber == 1002) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:35]];

}

if (ScoreNumber == 5000) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:40]];

    [Thousand play];

}

if (ScoreNumber == 5002) {

    [ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:35]];

}

}


- (void)GameOver {
    [Scorer invalidate];

[CountDownTimer invalidate];
[RoyMovement invalidate];
[RoyMovement2 invalidate];
[RoyMovement3 invalidate];
[ObstacleTimer invalidate];
[ObstacleTimer2 invalidate];
[ObstacleTimer3 invalidate];
[FuelMovement invalidate];
[FuelMovement2 invalidate];

ScoreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(331, 80, 140, 90);

[ScoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"04b_21" size:30]];

if (ScoreNumber > HighScoreNumber) {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:ScoreNumber forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
    HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];

    NewHighScore.hidden = NO;

}

if (ScoreNumber > 99) {

    Bronze.hidden = NO;
    Silver.hidden = YES;
    Gold.hidden = YES;
    Diamond.hidden = YES;

    Bronze.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze4.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze5.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze6.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze7.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze6.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze5.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze8.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze9.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze10.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze9.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bronze8.png"],

                              nil];

    [Bronze setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    Bronze.animationDuration = 1.2;
    [Bronze startAnimating];




}

if (ScoreNumber > 499) {

    Bronze.hidden = YES;
    Silver.hidden = NO;
    Gold.hidden = YES;
    Diamond.hidden = YES;

    Silver.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver4.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver3.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver2.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver5.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver6.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver7.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver6.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver5.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver8.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver9.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver10.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver9.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Silver8.png"],

                              nil];

    [Silver setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    Silver.animationDuration = 1.2;
    [Silver startAnimating];

}

if (ScoreNumber > 999) {

    Bronze.hidden = YES;
    Silver.hidden = YES;
    Gold.hidden = NO;
    Diamond.hidden = YES;

    Gold.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold7.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold8.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold9.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold10.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold9.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gold8.png"],

                            nil];

    [Gold setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    Gold.animationDuration = 1.2;
    [Gold startAnimating];

}

if (ScoreNumber > 4999) {

    Bronze.hidden = YES;
    Silver.hidden = YES;
    Gold.hidden = YES;
    Diamond.hidden = NO;

    Diamond.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond2.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond3.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond4.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond3.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond2.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond5.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond6.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond7.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond6.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond5.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond8.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond9.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond10.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond9.png"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"Diamond8.png"],

                               nil];

    [Diamond setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    Diamond.animationDuration = 1.2;
    [Diamond startAnimating];


}

}


- (void)viewDidLoad

{

ScoreNumber = 0;
ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];

HighScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
HighScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)HighScoreNumber];

}
```

Comment: This isn't complete code - you are missing several closing }s there is nothing in your Scoring method (at least as shown here) that will cause your problem.  I suggest you set a breakpoint in this method and single step through or show the full code for this method

Comment: @Paulw11 What about now?

Comment: Your `if` tests in `scoring` are definitely going to cause you some problems because you are using > - so when the score is, say, 1002 it will execute the code for >499 *and* >501 *and* >999 *and* greater than 1001 on every execution of the `scoring` method - continually resetting timers, playing sounds and so on.  Also there is no reason to use all of those different timer variables.  Once you have invalidated `RoyMovement` you can just assign the new timer to `RoyMovement`

Comment: So would == be better instead of >? And with the timers I can just change the timer interval for RoyMovement in the if statements, instead of using a new timer and invalidating the old one? @Paulw11

Comment: Yes == is better. You need to invalidate the timer and assign a new one but you can use the same variable to hold the reference to the new timer

Comment: @Paulw11 It didn't help... The score timer still affects the timers in the IBAction. The weird thing is that the game works on an iPhone with iOS 7, with this code.

Comment: So where doesn't it work?

Comment: You said that the games works in iOS7, so where doesn't it work? iOS 8?

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, yes exactly

Comment: And you are compiling this exact code and running it on iOS 7 or you have an older version running on iOS 7?

Comment: @Paulw11 I just changed the deployment target and base sdk to the latest, and then the problem occured

Comment: @Paulw11 I was developing it for iOS 7, and then I updated Xcode and the base sdk was changed to iOS 8, so I changed the deployment target to iOS 8 as well, and then the problem occured. If I change the base sdk and deployment target to iOS 7 it works on a device with iOS 7, but not a device with iOS 8.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with 64 bit code, but where I can't say

Comment: I am just guessing as to what the difference could be between iOS 7 and iOS 8 and 64 bit code is one of them, although 64 bit is supported on iOS7 too

Comment: @Paulw11 I appreciate your help man. Although it seems like it will take a while for me to figure this out... Like forever

Comment: This won't solve your problem but in the future always assign a timer to nil after the invalidation.